# Python error: TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, calculator

I am working on creating a change calculator that has to output a result similar to this:

```
{'TWENTY':1, 'TEN':1, 'FIVE':1, 'PENNY’ : 2}
{‘ONE’:1,'FIVE':1}
{‘ONE’:1}
{'PENNY':4,'NICKEL':1}
```

I am having issues with reading the data and accessing the indices because I have never worked with reading a .csv file before. I think the logic of my calculator should be fine. I realize there are more efficent ways to code it but I am on a time limit and this seemed logical to me. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
enter code here__author__ = 'austincolaizzi'

import csv

print("Enter in your file name: ")

file1 = input(" ")

txt1 = open(file1)


csv_txt1 = csv.reader(txt1)

#for row in csv_txt1:
    #print (row[0:2])


difference = 0
remainder = 0
change = {
    'Penny': 0,
    'Nickel': 0,
    'Dime': 0,
    'Quarter': 0,
    'Half Dollar': 0,
    'One': 0,
    'Two': 0,
    'Five': 0,
    'Ten': 0,
    'Twenty': 0,
    'Fifty': 0,
    'Hundred': 0,
}

for row in csv_txt1:
    if row[0] == row[1]:
        print ("You had exact change")
    elif row[0] > row[1]:
        print ("You need more money to purchase this")
else:
    difference = csv_txt1[1] - csv_txt1[0]
    if difference % 100 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif difference % 100 != 0:
        change['Hundred'] = difference / 100
        remainder = difference % 100
    elif remainder % 50 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % 50 != 0:
        change['Fifty'] = remainder / 50
        remainder = remainder % 50
    elif remainder % 20 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % 20 != 0:
        change['Twenty'] = remainder / 20
        remainder = remainder % 20
    elif remainder % 10 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % 10 != 0:
        change['Ten'] = remainder / 10
        remainder =  remainder % 10
    elif remainder % 5 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % 5 != 0:
        change['Five'] = remainder / 5
        remainder = remainder % 5
    elif remainder % 2 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder %2 != 0:
        change['Two'] = remainder / 2
        remainder = remainder % 2
    elif remainder % 1 == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder %1 != 0:
        change['Two'] = remainder / 1
        remainder = remainder % 1
    elif remainder % int(.50) == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % int(.50) != 0:
        change['Two'] = remainder / int(.50)
        remainder = remainder % int(.50)
    elif remainder % int(.25) == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % int(.25) != 0:
        change['Two'] = remainder / int(.25)
        remainder = remainder % int(.25)
    elif remainder % int(.10) == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % int(.10) != 0:
        change['Two'] = remainder / int(.10)
        remainder = remainder % int(.10)
    elif remainder % int(.05) == 0:
        remainder = remainder
    elif remainder % int(.05) != 0:
        change['Two'] = remainder / int(.05)
        remainder = remainder % int(.05)
    else:
        remainder = remainder / int(.01)


for key in change:
    if change[key] >= 1:
        print (change[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line after your else statement, you have `csv_txt1[1] - csv_txt1[0]`.

This should be `row[1] - row[0]`, as you have earlier.

Note you should have posted the traceback, which would have made this easier to debug as it shows the exact line the error occurred on.